# Ошибка при нажатии

Tags: java, android

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.tt.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:47)
```

Comment: вы пытаетесь получить доступ к данным которых нет..

Comment: даже не к данным, а к null-объекту